# How can I convince the Maritimes to join the thirteen colonies?

Tags: internal-consistency, alternate-history

The Maritimes for those who are unaware, are the eastern most provinces of Canada; New Brunswick, Nova Scotia and Prince Edward Island. When I look at history, I am always confused as to why these colonies did not join the the thirteen colonies and after a little research, I found [this question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/480/why-did-canada-not-join-the-american-revolution) of History Stack Exchange. Long story short; The [Canadiens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Canadian) were tired of war and content with British rule.

[image]

But what if this wasn't the case? What is the smallest change to history that would cause the Maritime Provinces to join the revolution against the British, forming the Sixteen Colonies? If possible, I would also like for the change to encompass Quebec and Ontario (which was smaller at the time).

Comment: I've never heard Quebec called part of the Maritimes, and my family is from Montreal. It certainly isn't officially.

Comment: @rek I'll reword to clarify what I mean

Comment: Make them not content with British rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reading of the History SE answer about the Maritimes not joining the American Revolution cited above, suggests the following.

- Get rid of the Quebec Act;
- Make British rule of Canada Francophobic and anti-Catholic;
- Make economic conditions favourable for joining the Thirteen Colonies and not sticking with the British Empire;
- Stop the Americans behaving like bastards towards the Canadians;
- Tick off all the factors that made the Canadians prefer the British to siding with the Americans and turn them around to favouring joining the Revolution.

Essentially the History SE answer has done all the heavy lifting. Use that information to, hypothetically, change the result